# Bash script: keep one line of local file in sync with remote file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, synchronization

I have searched high and low, but cannot seem to find a solution to this problem (maybe it doesn't exist?). Here is my problem:

I have a file on my local machine called myFile.txt. There is a file on a remote machine with the same name (myFile.txt). Both file structures look like this:

```
<tag1>November 22, 2012<tag1>
<tag2>version5.8<tag2>
<tag3>ASDFA23RASDF29ASDJ29DJ2<tag3>
```

Both files have this exact same layout. I need to write a script keeps the string in between `<tag3>` in sync for the two files (local and remote). I need to get the string from `<tag3>` on the remote server and compare it to the same string on my local machine. If there is a difference I need to change my local string to reflect the remote one.

What I've tried thus far:
I've grabbed the local string using awk, and assigned it to a variable. Easy enough. I ssh'ed into the remote server and attempted to use the same method to assign the remote string to a variable. As far as I can tell, this seems to be working. The issue is the variable doesn't come back to my local machine with a value (if that makes sense). This is how I'm attempting to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName="myFile.txt"
logon="myUserName@remoteServer.com"


localString=$(awk -F "<tag3>" '{print $2}' $fileName)

x=$(ssh $logon "remoteString=$(awk -F "<tag3>" '{print $2}' $fileName); echo $remoteString")
echo "remote string = $x" 

if [ $localString == $x ]; then
echo "The 2 auth keys are EQUAL!!!"
else
echo "The 2 auth keys are NOT equal!!!"
fi
```

I can see the variable being assigned when I echo out $remoteString. From my understanding this is happening on the remote server though as I'm getting the correct string printed to console followed by "command not found". The next line echo's "remote string = ". So $x is either losing it's value or is never properly assigned. I've tried varying this line where $x is assigned many many time, but have not had any luck.

Other ideas:
If this isn't possible I'm beginning to think maybe I need to do a scp of the file, bring it over to my server, make the comparison, and then delete the copied filed. I would need to change the name of the copy before moving it to my local machine, or else I will overwrite my file. Also, it would seem more efficient not to have to make a secure copy because this script will have to run on many machines, and the file will potentially be a lot bigger than 3 lines. I've looked into diff, but can't find a way to get it to compare just one line.

I am fairly new to bash scripting so please forgive me if I am missing something obvious. Thank you for any help as it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash 
fileName="myFile.txt"
logon="myUserName@remoteServer.com"

sedcommand='/^<tag3>.*<tag3>$/{s/<tag3>\(.*\)<tag3>/\1/p;q}'

localString=$( sed -n $sedcommand "$fileName" )
remoteString=$( ssh "$logon" "sed -n '$sedcommand' \"$fileName\"" )

if [[ $localString == $remoteString ]]; then
    echo "The 2 auth keys are EQUAL!!!"
else
    echo "The 2 auth keys are NOT equal!!!"
fi
```

(which seems simpler than your method). The `sed` command finds the first occurence of a line starting by `<tag3>` and ending by `<tag3>` and removes the tags so as to transfer only the "auth key". There's no guard against files that don't exist, or against the tag not being find. This detail is left to the reader. But the script is safe regarding spaces in file names and doesn't use two nested subshells!

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much. When I first sat down to do this I attempted sed, but couldn't figure out how to extract my string correctly. I then moved on to awk, which I was able to figure out pretty quickly. I need to work more with regex. I think that was the obstacle as far as sed went.

Answer (score 1):

There's a escaping issue with the `ssh` commands - you should escape the `$` inside the `ssh` parameters.

Then, I just replaced the `remoteString=$(awk ....); echo $remoteString` with just `awk ....`. If not, there was some issue with a leading blank line that made the strings to not match - and it seems pretty useless to store a command's output just to `echo`ing it.

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName="myFile.txt"
logon="myUserName@remoteServer.com"


localString=$(awk -F "<tag3>" '{print $2}' $fileName)

x=$(ssh $logon "awk -F '<tag3>' '{print \$2}' $fileName")
echo "remote string = $x" 

if [ "$localString" == "$x" ]; then
        echo "The 2 auth keys are EQUAL!!!"
else
        echo "The 2 auth keys are NOT equal!!!"
fi
```

Comment: Interesting result from this. $x is echo'ing a value, but it's value is equal to the whole file. Maybe I have to change my awk expression? But it works fine locally?

Comment: @nycfdtd I think I didn't get your comment. The only difference between the script I posted and the script I'm running here to test is the `fileName` and `logon`. I'm running it against `localhost`, so both `awk` are being performed with the same file. And the file content are the 3 lines you posted on your question. I don't know if it is any difference in your system. Could there be any issue?

Comment: Not sure desert69. For some reason when the same awk expression was run on the remote server it assigned the whole files contents to $x. So the whole file printed out when echo'ing $x's value. The strange thing is: the same exact awk expression is used on the local machine and that pull just the value between the <tag3>.

Comment: @nycfdtd try it `ssh`ing against `localhost`. If that works, then there's a problem with the remote file, or `awk`, or maybe the shell? Seems strange...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
x=$(ssh $logon "remoteString=$(awk -F "<tag3>" '{print $2}' $fileName); echo $remoteString")
```

to

```
x=$(ssh $logon "remoteString=$(awk -F '<tag3>' '{print $2}' $fileName); echo $remoteString")
```

i.e.: change `"<tag3>"` to `'<tag3>'`

I have a feeling that your current use of the double quotes is actually breaking the intended use of your ssh command.

---

As a side note: always wrap your variables in double quotes when you single `[`'s for condition tests:

```
if [ $localString == $x ]; then
```

would be safer as:

```
if [ "$localString" == "$x" ]; then
```

or

```
# this also works, but less portable
if [[ $localString == $x ]]; then
```

The reason is that if either variable evaluates to the null string (suppose in this case `x` is empty), bash would see something like this instead: `if [ ASDFA23RASDF29ASDJ29DJ2 == ]; then`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still having same issue though. The string is being echo'ed out correctly on the line you quoted, but when I try to echo $x in the next line, the variable loses it's value.